# Clearing session from browser cache in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I updated my app to initialize routes in callback after loading the model from database call.

Since doing this my browser (Chrome for dev) caches data very persistently. Any tips on how to force browser to reload with new data or can clear session?

Also concerned about ensuring deployed apps would use latest data.

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of what you are doing? Are you using `$http` or `$resource` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**"clearing cache"** is not as easy as it should be. Instead of clearing cache on my browsers, I realized that "touching" the server files cached will actually change the date and time of the source file cached on the server (Tested on Edge, Chrome and Firefox) and most browsers will automatically download the most current fresh copy of whats on your server (code, graphics any multimedia too). I suggest you just copy the most current scripts on the server and **"do the touch thing"** solution before your program runs, so it will change the date of all your problem files to a most current date and time, then it downloads a fresh copy to your browser:

```
  <?php
    touch('/www/control/file1.js');
    touch('/www/control/file2.js');
    touch('/www/control/file2.js');
   ?>
```

then ... the rest of your program...

It took me some time to resolve this issue (as many browsers act differently to different commands, but they all check time of files and compare to your downloaded copy in your browser, if different date and time, will do the refresh), If you can't go the supposed right way, there is always another usable and better solution to it. Best Regards and happy camping.  By the way touch(); or alternatives work in many programming languages inclusive in javascript bash sh php and you can include or call them in html.